# How do I run common commands (bundle, rake db:migrate, etc) from sublime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext3

I'm looking for an option similar to the [the rspec runner](https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests) for Sublime editor. Or an easy way to enhance a current plugin to add shortcuts to common tasks when developing Rails or Ruby applications.